# Profile with devise rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, devise

What is the best way to create a profile for a user actually i am creating the profile just after the user registration

```
  has_one :profile, dependent: :destroy
  after_create :create_profil

  def create_profile
    @profile = Profile.create(user: self)
  end
```

but the profile must have other information like experiences, educations, skills,...
 so I'm wondering what is the best way to do that, I'm thinking to use nested attributes is this would be a nice solution?

Answer (score 0):

You should visit the rails basics on creating association.

1. if you insist of having single profile for a user, you can use one-to-one association.

Check following link:
http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#choosing-between-belongs-to-and-has-one

Comment: he has already a relation between users and profile he is just wondering if there is not a better solution than the one he posted

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you to keep the profile data in the user model, because it will be more natural to access to that information later

```
user.skills = "some skills" 
user.experience = "a lot of experience"
```

instead of the profile model

```
user.profile.skills = "some skills" 
user.profile.experience = "a lot of experience"
```

But to answer your question the best way to do that is creating a profile model with a one to one relation (i am assuming that your are using rails 4)

```
rails g model profile field1:type field2:type user:references
```

and then add the relation to each model

### models/user.rb

```
has_one :profile, :dependent => :destroy
```

### models/profile.rb

```
belongs_to :user
```

For the nested attributes i will recommend you to see this [railscasts](http://railscasts.com/episodes/196-nested-model-form-revised?view=comments) that explain how to use them and then instead of creating by your self you should use the [cocoon gem](https://github.com/nathanvda/cocoon) to make it more simple.

I hope it helps :D